# image_tag not showing paperclip uploaded image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, file-upload, paperclip

Hi i'm using paperclip to upload and save the company avatar on my app. This is how it looks on company model:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

I'm also using an initializer, paperclip.rb:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = :fog
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:fog_credentials] = {:provider => "Local", :local_root => "#{Rails.root}/public"}
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:fog_directory] = ""
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:fog_host] = "http://localhost:3000"
```

Images are saved correctly, but when i try to display them like this:

```
<%= image_tag @company.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
```

It only shows the name of the file and no image.

The html looks like this:

```
<img alt="Mini cooper" src="http://localhost:3000/companies/avatars/000/000/003/thumb/mini-cooper.jpg%3F1416616058">
```

And if i take out the characters after .jpg like the following:

```
http://localhost:3000/companies/avatars/000/000/003/thumb/mini-cooper.jpg
```

I see the image just fine. But the helper just builds the url with those extra characters.
Any ideas?

Comment: hi! same problem after update rails admin and paperclip. previous  project with same gem list(but older gem version) work fine and opened correctly,with this charaters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your issue is related to a [recent commit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1706) which doesn't properly escape the timestamp. A temporary workaround is to disable the timestamp while a fix is worked-out.

For individual calls

```
@company.avatar.url(:thumb, timestamp:false)
```

Or you can disable this globally but putting the following line within your `config/initializers/paperclip.rb` file.

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:use_timestamp] = false
```